# Auto scroll function in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll

Hi I am trying to implement a autoscroll function on my webapp. After page load the page should scroll automatically to the bottom without an animation. I need it for a little chat application where after page loading the latest `list item`s should become displayed. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1512/).

```
// this version wont work:
myscroll = $('#chatOutput');
myscroll.scrollTop(myscroll.get(0).scrollHeight);
//this wont work too:
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
   $(window).load(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){ 

    $(document).scrollTop($('.chatPost:last-child').offset().top);

    }, 1000);
   });
```

Comment: please check it again added setTimeout

Comment: some script loading after this causing the issue

Comment: so load this after all scripts loaded